# Installing from bios with no current os, help

Tags: system-installation, laptop

I'm a complete newbie to this, so I'm going to need a full walkthrough with as little jargon as possible.
Short story: I bought a used laptop that's in great shape off ebay. Dell Latitude, 16 gb ram, 128 gb ssd, i7-5600u core. Bit old, good heart. However, it has no os, just the bios. How can I get Ubuntu on here with as little fuss as possible?
I have only worked with Windows vista, 8, and 10, plus chrome os and I've never had to install an is before.
I have access to computers running on chrome os and Windows 10, plus mysterious hard drives my dad left when he died. I also have some flash drives in varying states of functionality, and HDMI cables that were being used to connect my previous laptop to the tv because the screen broke but all else was fine. My dad also left a whole drawer of mysterious cables I don't know the names of. Hope this is enough info, tell me if in my ignorance I left something out. Thanks in advance!

Comment: New Dell often needs UEFI update and SSD firmware update. Check your versions and update if needed. Dell often needs UEFI/BIOS setting for drives changed from RAID or Intel SRT to AHCI. New systems have two ways to boot install media UEFI or BIOS and that is then how it installs. You want UEFI.  https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFI Skip Windows section unless also installing Windwos and install that first. http://askubuntu.com/questions/221835/installing-ubuntu-on-a-pre-installed-windows-10-with-uefi

Comment: Have you looked at any of the tutorials or guides?  https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/tutorial-install-ubuntu-desktop#0  (being the first that a search came up with)

Answer (score 0):

Well you will need a working windows or ubuntu running computer to make a usb bootable disk for installing ubuntu on your laptop. 8gb flash drive should be enough for this job. download the setup iso file from official [ubuntu](https://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop) website. go for the iso with AMD64 architecture. Then if you are making the usb on windows, download [RUFUS](https://rufus.ie/en_IE.html) and on linux based systems you can use [etcher](https://www.balena.io/etcher/) for making bootable usb drives. The process is straight forward from there. (both software) select the .iso file, select the drive. and start. For rufus you might want to use dd mode.

The laptop should detect and load the setup menu automatically. if not then google your laptop model for startup boot selection key. everything else should be fine.